# Lie algebra action on complex algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras

Suppose that $X$ is a complex algebraic variety, i.e. it is integral, separated, and of finite-type over $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional complex Lie algebra.

Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on $X$, i.e. we have a homomorphism $\phi:\mathfrak{g}\to \mathrm{Vec}(X)$, where $\mathrm{Vec}(X)$ is the Lie algebra of vector fields on $X$.  Suppose further that for every closed point $x\in X$, the canonical morphism
$$ \mathfrak{g}\to T_xX$$
is surjective.  This should be the way to say the action is 'homogeneous'.  My question is: does this imply $X$ is smooth?  Or at least that the tangent sheaf is locally free?  Feel free to assume $X$ is, say, normal if that is necessary.

Comment: Lie algebra of which vector fields? polynomial? holomorphic?...

Comment: Polynomial vector fields.  By $\text{Vec}(X)$ I simply mean the global sections of the tangent sheaf of $X$, where the tangent sheaf is the coherent sheaf whose sections on an affine open $U=\text{Spec}(A)$ are the derivations of the algebra $A$.

Comment: Crossposted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2991972/lie-algebra-action-on-complex-algebraic-variety).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the answer should be positive.

Suppose by contradiction, that there is a singular point $x\in X$. Let us take an affine neighbourhood $U$ of $x$. Let $f_1,\ldots, f_n$ be the regular functions that generate the ring of functions on $U$. This functions give us an embedding $\varphi: U\to \mathbb C^n$ and the lie algebra action on $U$ lifts to an action on $\mathbb C^n$. Now, locally (say in analytic topology) this action should preserve $\varphi(U)$. But this is a contradiction. Indeed, take at $x$ a vector $v$ that lies in the tangent space to $\varphi(U)$ at $x$, but not in the tangent cone. Then by our assumptions there should exist a vector field whose local flow close to $\varphi(x)$ preserves $\varphi(U)$ and which is equal to $v$ at $x$. But such a field clearly can not preserve $\varphi(U)$ since it pushes $x$ out of $\varphi(U)$, contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Can you define the tangent cone?  I've never seen it before and can't find a definition.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Here is one definition: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Tangent_cone

Comment: Wow thank you I clearly was not putting much effort into my googling the first time around lol.

Comment: So it seems from your proof that the following more general statement should be true: a variety is smooth if and only if at every point every tangent vector can be lifted to a vector field in some open neighborhood of that point.  Your argument would carry through in the same way.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, it seems so (say, for safety one sticks to the class of varieties that you have chosen)